# How to run a grunt task on the files in the current working directory

Tags: gruntjs

I have a task where I would like to run and operate on the files in a current directory.

What I have so far is:

```
grunt.registerTask('getfiles', function() {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(process.cwd());
    console.log(files);
});
```

The problem is, it only ever outputs the top level files.

My directory looks like this:

```
-node-modules
-content
 -file1
 -file2
-Gruntfile.js
-package.json
```

And it currently outputs:

```
[ '.git',
'.gitignore',
'Gruntfile.js',
'content',
'node_modules',
'package.json' ]
```

But I would like it to output:

```
['file1,
'file2]
```

when I run grunt inside the content directory.

How would I go about doing this?

Update:

I just realised that I can do:

```
grunt --base .
```

Some additional information:

The desired outcome is to be able to rename specific files with a command like:

```
grunt rename file1 file2
```

Comment: Why not just use grunt's globbing functionality? As it is, you're not really trying to operate on files in the cwd, you seem to want some files from some specific subdir.

Comment: @pvg Thanks. I've read through the documentation and having trouble understanding how it would be used in this case. Can you provide some sort of example of how I would achieve this through globbing?

Comment: This is covered pretty directly in the docs, for instance https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks  "Most tasks perform file operations, so Grunt provides a built-in infrastructure to retrieve the files a task should process. The advantage is that this logic doesn't have to be implemented again by tasks authors.". The whole point of that is, grunt provides extensive facilities for selecting files so you don't have to code it explicitly into your tasks. The vast majority of tasks work like this.